# Image conversion using BufferedImage and ImageIO

Tags: java, image, image-processing, javax.imageio, image-conversion

I want to change the extension of an image from png to jpg but while doing that I'm also scaling the image in lower dimensions. How can i do both things at once?

Comment: Simple. You read the image in, then use Image.getScaledVersion, then write the image out with the new image file format

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Are there any particular part you have trouble with? I'd start by breaking the task in 3: 1. Read the PNG to `BufferedImage`. 2. Scale the image. 3. Write the image as JPEG. Trying to do all at once just makes things more complex.